# installing oracle database 21c is not working,

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle21c

I had installed the oracle 21c for use the sql plus before and when it is almost installed again the bar of download come back to zero and says that wizard was interrupted. I been for hours looking for answers, please what can i do?

Comment: look for a log file in oraInventory/logs/installActions<timestamp>.log and see what it says.  Nobody here can help you w/o more details.

Answer (score 0):

You might have uninstalled older version before you start installing 12c. Make sure you have restarted your system after that try to install it again using setup.exe